# Custom Function AddIn for office 365

Tags: office365

I have office insider subscription and developed a sample for custom function and published in iis and it is working fine in my excel as I have office insider subscription . But my question is that , other than me , do the other end user who uses the excel without office insider will able to access

Answer (score 0):

as CustomFunctions are now generally available, users on the monthly channel (“May update”) will be able to use them when centrally deployed.